# How to manage function call in series using node js

Tags: node.js

I have used step even then function get called parallel, the execution should be  in series please tell me where i am going wrong.

```
   //sample code
   var step=require('step')
   step(
   function first()
   {
   process();//calling function here
   return this; returning this to next function
   },
   function second()
   {
   process2();//calling another fun here
   return this;
   },
   function third()
   {
   process3();//calling function here
   return this; returning this to next function
   } 
   );//step end here
```

please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
var sync =require('async');
sync.series([
function(callback){
console.log("calling one");
callback(null, 'one');
},
function(callback){
console.log('two');
callback(null, 'two');
},
]);
```

Hello,

You have to synchronize these functions. Here step will not work for recursive functions.

Try this, Hop you will get you answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the link:

Video: http://nodetuts.com/02-callback-pattern.html

Text: http://nodetuts.com/02-callback-pattern.html#-1

This may help you..